# For what values $\alpha$ for complex z $\ln(z^{\alpha}) = \alpha \ln(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For example, when $\alpha = 2$, $\ln(z^{2}) \neq 2\ln(z)$, because argument z is determined up to constant $2 \pi k$. So

$$
\ln(z^{2}) = \ln(z) + \ln(z) = \ln(z_{k_{1}}) + \ln(z_{k_{2}}) \neq 2\ln(z_{k_{3}}).
$$

Of course, two of correct answers - $1, -1$. But I know, that there are an infinite number of answers for $\alpha$. Can you help me?

Comment: What is your definition of $z^\alpha$, given complex numbers $z$ and $\alpha\ $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189703/does-ii-and-i1-over-e-have-more-than-one-root-in-0-2-pi/191966#191966) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84578/logarithm-of-products-in-mathbbc),

$Log (a+ib)^{x+iy}$
$=\frac{1}{2}x\log (a^2+b^2)-y(2m\pi+\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a})+i(\frac{1}{2}y\log (a^2+b^2)+x(2m\pi+\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a}))$

$Log (a+ib)= \frac{1}{2}\log (a^2+b^2)+i(2n\pi+\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a})$

$(x+iy)Log (a+ib)$
$=\frac{1}{2}x\log (a^2+b^2)-y(2n\pi+\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a})+i(x(2n\pi+\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a})+\frac{1}{2}y\log (a^2+b^2))$

The principal values will be same if $-\pi<\frac{1}{2}y\log (a^2+b^2)+x\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a}\le \pi$ else $2r\pi$ (where $r$ is any integer) must be added to this argument to adjust its value in $(-\pi, \pi]$.

If $x=0$ or $(b=0$ and $a>0 ⇔ \tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a}=0)$ , the condition becomes $-\pi<\frac{1}{2}y\log (a^2+b^2)\le \pi$

If $y=0$ or $a^2+b^2=1 ⇔ \log (a^2+b^2)=0$, the condition becomes $-\pi<x\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a}\le \pi$

If $y=0$ or $a^2+b^2=1$ and $x=-1$ the condition becomes $-\pi<-\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a}\le \pi\implies \pi>\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a}\ge -\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a}$ which is true for all $a,b$.

If $y=0,x=2$ the condition becomes $-\pi<2\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a}\le \pi $

$\implies -\frac{\pi}2<\tan ^{-1}\frac{b}{a}\le \frac{\pi}2$ i.e, $a>0$.

Comment: Thank you! But how did you get a condition
$$
-\pi < \frac{1}{2}y ln(a^{2} + b^{2}) + x arctg\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) \leqslant \pi ?
$$

Comment: Please look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Principal_value and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: Thank you! You helped me very much.

Comment: There is another solution of this problem, as I think. For simplifying I make for $\alpha$ value $x = Real$. So for $z = re^{i(\varphi + 2 \pi k)}$ I can earn for multivalued $Ln(z^{\alpha})$

$$
Ln(z^{\alpha}) = \alpha\left(i(\varphi + 2 \pi k) + ln(r)\right) + 2 \pi j i = \alpha \left(i(\varphi + 2 \pi k) + ln(r) \right) + 2 \pi j i \qquad (.1),
$$

and for $\alpha Ln(z)$

$$
\alpha(Ln(z)) = \alpha (i(\varphi + 2 \pi n) + ln(r)) .
$$

So

$$
 \alpha (Ln(z)) = Ln(z^{\alpha}) \Rightarrow |(.1)| \Rightarrow 2 \pi i ( j  + \alpha k ) = \alpha 2 \pi i n.
$$

Comment: So, $\alpha = \frac{1}{n}, n$ - any whole number.