# Determine principal value

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Determine all complex values of $(ie^{\pi})^{i}$ and indicate the principal value.

My attempt: $(ie^{\pi})^{i}=e^{i\log(ie^{\pi})}=e^{i[\ln|ie^{\pi}|+i\arg(ie^{\pi})]}$

Note that $\ln|ie^{\pi}|=\ln e^{\pi}=\pi$ and $\arg(ie^{\pi})=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ for all integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $(ie^{\pi})^{i}=e^{i\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}-2k\pi}=-e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}-2k\pi}$

Principal value is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

A few parts I'm not quite sure. Like can the principal part be $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Also can someone help me to check whether I do it correctly or not?

EDIT: From the definition of [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value), I obtain $e^{i\operatorname{Log}(ie^{\pi})}=e^{i\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}}=-e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201991/for-what-values-alpha-for-complex-z-lnz-alpha-alpha-lnz

Answer (score 1):

We can write
\begin{align}
i&=0+1i\\
&=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
From equation $(1)$, 
\begin{align}
(ie^\pi)^i&=(e^\frac{i\pi}{2}e^\pi)^i\\
&=(e^\frac{i^2\pi}{2})e^{i\pi}\\  
&=e^\frac{-\pi}{2}(-1)\\
&=\frac{-1}{e^\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: is the second equality in second line valid? We can expand the complex exponent like real exponent?