# Complex Numbers, Complicated Powers

Tags: complex-numbers, rational-numbers, natural-numbers, real-numbers

We know there are two non-real imaginary numbers like $a$, $b$ such that the power $a^{b}$ is a real number. For example we have $i^{i}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{\pi}}}$.

**Question:** Are there two non-real imaginary numbers like $a, b$ such that $a^{b}$ is a natural/rational number?

Comment: Put $x=0,a^2+b^2=1$ here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201991/for-what-values-alpha-for-complex-z-lnz-alpha-alpha-lnz/202164#202164)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, but, due to the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond-Schneider_theorem), they would have to be transcendental.