# Calculating complex logarithm

Tags: logarithms

I have to calculate the following log:

a) log(-4)
b) log (3i)

I don't really know what to do..

a) $ log(-4) = log|-4| + i\cdot arg(-4) + 2ki\pi = log4 + ?? + 2ki\pi$

b) $ log(3i) = log|3i| + i\dot arg(3i) + 2ki\pi = log(3) + ?? + 2ki\pi$

Comment: Do you know what the arg function is?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201991/for-what-values-alpha-for-complex-z-lnz-alpha-alpha-lnz/202164#202164

Comment: Hi, I googled arg-function, it helped me alot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**. Concerning the first question, you can note that
log(-4) = log(4 i^2) = log(4) + 2 log(e^(i Pi /2)) = log(4) + i Pi
Can you continue with this ?